# How to copy Vertical one line to paste at same file another Vertical in excel with C#

Tags: c#, excel

How to copy Vertical one line to paste at same file another Vertical in excel with C#?
for example, like a in vertical A have `[a,a] == A [a,b] == B` and I want paste it in vertical B `[b,a] == A [b,b] == B` with C# at Excel File..

Comment: Which library are you using? Interop, EPPlus, NPOI?

Comment: I Try to using Interop and I did it !